# How can I achieve ordering on a collection of simple objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "UserStrings")
@Column(name = "string")
@OrderBy
private List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
```

This results in a table:

```
UserStrings
-----------
User_object_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
string DEFAULT NULL
```

which is fine, but I get the collection as a `org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag` which is unordered, and each time I iterate on it, I get different order. I tried using `@OrderBy`, but it doesn't work on collection of strings, I suppose it would if it was a collection of entities.

I am absolutely sure that I want it to stay a collection of strings, there is no point in creating a new entity for them.

I would like to have the strings sorted by their value, so OrderColumn also (I think) is not for this, because it creates additional column for ordering.

Anyone knows what I can do to get them in an ordered collection like ArrayList or LinkedList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to be the bearer of bad news but this seems to be a [known hibernate issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6875), unresolved as-yet.

Comment: good news, it has just been resolved - [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6875). I'll check it as soon as it is released.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted) might be helpful.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID")
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = TicketComparator.class)
public SortedSet<Ticket> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}
```

Comment: how is this related? OP said "I am absolutely sure that I want it to stay a collection of strings, there is no point in creating a new entity for them"